# Fixing class and packages in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, class, layout, settings

trouble with eclipse see picture. I can't create classes and packages. I can only create new projects and examples. How can i fix this? Can i reset the settings for this?
Thx in advance.

[image: Here is what i get when i try to create something in Eclipse]

Comment: Right click on 'src' and the context menu will allow you to create packages. Right click on a package and the context menu will allow you to create classes.

Comment: you clicked on the class, right click on the package.

Comment: Hello Micheal it's the same thing.. I have tried

Comment: Have you tried selecting **Other...**? (Or pressing **Ctrl+N**?)

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the ***Java* perspective** or use the *Project Explorer* instead of the *Package Explorer*.